# Как правильно написать предложение, с запятой или нет

Tags: местоимение

Лосиха толкнула лосенка в реку и сама поплыла рядом с ним. Это предложение сложное или с однородными членами? Нужна ли запятая перед союзом и? Каким членом предложения будет слово сама?

Answer (score 1):

***Лосиха толкнула лосенка в реку, и сама поплыла рядом с ним.***

В этом предложении многоликое местоимение САМА выполняет роль подлежащего во втором предложении сложносочинённого предложения, так как оно используется вместо личного местоимения ОНА. Запятая нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Это простое предложение, запятая не нужна. Сам - обстоятельство образа действия.

Comment: Из Академической грамматики

    § 2003. Распространяющие члены с двунаправленными отношениями формально и семантически зависят не от одного распространяемого члена, а одновременно от двух. <...> В предложении Мальчик построил эту модель сам. определяющий член сам относится как к подлежащему ({сам мальчик}), так и к сказуемому ({построил сам}).
Значит, сам и подлежащее и ОД.

Comment: В предложении Директору нужно разобраться самому определяющий член самому относится как к субъектному детерминанту директору ({самому директору}), так и к инфинитиву разобраться ({самому разобраться}). Члены предложения с двунаправленными связями, имеющие одновременно разные значения и выполняющие вследствие этого функции различных ЧП, — синкретичные ЧП.

Comment: Но Розенталь в подобный примерах ( в справочники есть подобный пример) не считает Сам подлежащим.

Comment: В приведенном у Розенталя примере местоимение сам используется в значении ‘самостоятельно, лично’ и, таким образом, выполняет функцию обстоятельства. В моем  же примере значение ‘самостоятельно, лично’ не подходит по контексту, и поэтому местоимение не выполняет роли обстоятельства.

Answer (score 0):

Да, однородные члены, запятая н нужна. Но я сомневаюсь, что "сама" - это обстоятельство

Из словаря:

САМ, I. местоим. сущ. 1. Указывает на лицо или предмет, которые лично, непосредственно производят действие или испытывают какое-л. состояние. Скажите об этом сами. Всех угощал, а сам и не притронулся. Поезжайте! - А сама?

Думаю, что здесь мы, скорее, имеем дело именно с местоименным существительным, отнесенным к производителю действия - лосиха сама. Тогда это больше похоже на указательную или выделительную частицу.

Comment: поплыла как? - сама.

Comment: Я всё сделаю (как?) сам.  Это другое значение: указывает на лицо или предмет, которые совершают действие самостоятельно, без постороннего вмешательства.  Но здесь "поплыла сама" - это не "поплыла самостоятельно".

Answer (score 0):

С интересом прочитал все ответы и комментарии, но почему-то никто не обратил внимания на препозиционное расположение местоимения "сама", которое в таком случае "подсказывает"  подлежащее "она": "Лосиха толкнула лосенка в реку, и (она)сама поплыла рядом с ним". Если бы слово "сама" находилось после сказуемого (поплыла сама), тогда оно выполняло бы обстоятельственную функцию. Понимаю, что многие будут возражать, но я так чувствую эту ситуацию

Comment: Виктор, а вот аналогичное предложение: Автор прочитал корректуру и сам внёс нужные исправления. Запятую поставите? Здесь тоже не нужна запятая. Это пример из справочника Розенталя.

Comment: Виктор, опубликовала свой ответ, потом только прочитала Ваш. Согласна с Вами.

Comment: Менять, подставлять и что-то домысливать в таких случаях нежелательно,  все эти подстановки искажают начальную структуру предложения, и мы получаем другую синтаксическую конструкцию. Вот реальные примеры без запятой: "Цивилизация, как говорится, сама пашет и сама топчет. Тётка Маница не решалась его беспокоить и сама занималась всеми хозяйскими делами. Утром за ним заехала, как обычно, машина, чтобы отвезти его на службу, и отвезла, но назад никого не привезла и сама больше не вернулась".

Comment: В то же время встречаются  авторские варианты с запятой, но там союз И имеет, скорее,  присоединительное значение, делается пауза в распространенном предложении: "Однако в умах миллионов она по-прежнему занимает место "тени Леннона", и сама регулярно подтверждает этот образ очень жёсткой защитой всего, что касается авторского наследия Джона".

Comment: А вот и текст нашелся: "Лосиха толкнула лосенка верхней вислой губой в реку, и сама поплыла рядом с ним".  Мне кажется, что бОльшая распространенность повлияла на постановку запятой. Да и ситуации описываются разные, действия разные, это тот случай, когда предложение с однородными сказуемыми можно рассматривать как сложное предложение. Думаю, что решение здесь авторское, но лучше поставить запятую.